# Flutter Stack Widget: Bound a layer's size to the size of the underlying layer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have a Card with a column (dynamic size). I want to display an overlay (semi transparent + icon) over the whole card, without altering the card's size.

I have coded an example by using a Stack widget. [Run on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/6070fb0dfbdc690153691a7d0b6c0699?)

The problem is, that the overlay should adapt to the size of the content in the layer below.
But how does the Overlay know the size of that other layer?

`double.infinity` won't work, because the size of the card is not fixed and can't be fixed, because the content has a dynamic size.

```dart
Card(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          // Content
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              // Content of dynamic size
              Text("q23123"),
              Text("q23123"),
              Text("q23123"),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Display Overlay"),
                onPressed: (() {
                  if (_showOverlay == false) {
                    setState(() {
                      _showOverlay = true;
                    });
                  }
                }),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          // Overlay
          _showOverlay == true
              ? Container(
                  height: double.infinity, // Overlay is too big -> should adabt to
                  width: double.infinity, // the size of the layer underneath
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.red],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container( // Overlay deactivated
                  height: 0,
                  width: 0,
                ),
        ],
      ),
      color: Colors.blue,
    ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In this case, you can use `GlobalKey` to get `yourRenderBox.size` 
code snippet

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showOverlay = false;
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  Size _getSizes() {
    final RenderBox yourRenderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    return yourRenderBox.size;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
          Padding(
            key: _key,
          ...
          // Overlay
          _showOverlay == true
              ? Container(
                  height: _getSizes().height,
                  width: _getSizes().width,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Problem'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _showOverlay = false;
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  Size _getSizes() {
    final RenderBox yourRenderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    return yourRenderBox.size;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Card(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          // Content
          Padding(
            key: _key,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              // Content of dynamic size
              Text("q23123"),
              Text("q23123"),
              Text("q23123"),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Display Overlay"),
                onPressed: (() {
                  if (_showOverlay == false) {
                    setState(() {
                      _showOverlay = true;
                    });
                  }
                }),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
          // Overlay
          _showOverlay == true
              ? Container(
                  height: _getSizes().height,
                  width: _getSizes().width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.red],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  // Overlay deactivated
                  height: 0,
                  width: 0,
                ),
        ],
      ),
      color: Colors.blue,
    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue, and as of september 2022, @chunhunghan solution didn't work for me: `final RenderBox yourRenderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();` is the line that breaks my code with: `A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox'.`

So I came up with another approach, inspired by flutter's [Widget of the Week video about Positioned](https://youtu.be/EgtPleVwxBQ), where no Keys are needed, simply a **`Stack()`** with two layers: bottom is dynamic-sized, and top is wrapped inside a **`Positioned.fill()`** widget that will adapt to the bottom layer size automatically.

Simplified code looks like this:

```dart
class MyStackState extends State < MyStack > {
  bool _showOverlay = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // we set up the Stack
    return Stack(
      children: [

        // Content of dynamic size (bottom layer)
        Padding(
          // your dynamic content here...
        ),

        // Overlay (top layer that adapts to the size of bottom layer)
        if (_showOverlay == true)
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Container(
              // your overlay here...
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

*Note that the `Positioned.fill()` will **strictly** take the size of the underlying layer, so if the underlying layer is of height 0 or width 0, then nothing will be rendered, not even if the `Positioned.fill()` had sized content inside, for example in my case I needed a `CircularProgressIndicator()` there to let the user know something was processing... it didn't show if content was empty.*

I edited the DartPad link you provided with a functioning example of this solution, hope it helps! [Edited DartPad with Positioned.fill() solution](https://dartpad.dev/?id=114cc5b01d0221ffd1821b21bacab691).

Answer (score 0):

Make Container as a parent of your widget, modified code :

```
Container(
   decoration: _showOverlay ? BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.red],
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, 
                children: [
                // Content of dynamic size
                Text("q23123"),
                Text("q23123"),
                Text("q23123"),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Display Overlay"),
                  onPressed: (() {
                    if (_showOverlay == false) {
                      setState(() {
                        _showOverlay = true;
                      });
                    }
                  }),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
```